# Android crashes in TextView with IndexOutOfBoundsException and no trace of custom code

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie

My Android app crashes somewhere in TextView on a device running Android9. It happens during param validation in SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange. I've quite a few TextView objects in my app, and it's not clear, which one exactly caused the problem and why, since no custom code has been provided in the stack trace.

It's a very rare crash and I'm not able to reproduce it, so using a debugger is not an option. Play Store reports the following device, build and version for this crash:

```
Samsung Galaxy S10+ (beyond2q), Android 9
```

I've decompiled SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange and it looks as follows with line #1326 pointing to "throw" statement under the last condition:

```
start < 0 || end < 0
```

**SpannableStringBuilder#checkRange code:**

```
private void checkRange(final String operation, int start, int end) {
    if (end < start) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(operation + " " +
                region(start, end) + " has end before start");
    }

    int len = length();

    if (start > len || end > len) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(operation + " " +
                region(start, end) + " ends beyond length " + len);
    }

    if (start < 0 || end < 0) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(operation + " " +
                region(start, end) + " starts before 0");
    }
}
```

**I've two questions about it:**

1. Is there any way to identify a place in custom code where the crash has happened ?
2. Is there any way to fix it at app level or this is an Android's platform problem that requires a system fix?

**Stack Trace:**

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange (SpannableStringBuilder.java:1326)
      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:682)
      at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan (SpannableStringBuilder.java:674)
      at android.text.method.ArrowKeyMovementMethod.onTouchEvent (ArrowKeyMovementMethod.java:255)
      at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent (TextView.java:11355)
      at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:13484)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3222)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2845)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3222)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2845)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3222)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2845)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3222)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2845)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3222)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2845)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3222)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2845)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:697)
      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1879)
      at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:3487)
      at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
      at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:655)
      at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:13732)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6119)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:5897)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:5346)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5365)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5524)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5373)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5581)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:5346)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:5399)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5365)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5373)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver 
(ViewRootImpl.java:5346)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:8408)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:8341)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:8294)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:8523)
      at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:198)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (MessageQueue.java)
      at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:326)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:181)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7037)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: Are your `TextView`s defined in code or `xml`? Are they assigned values in code? Put a debugger before `setText` or similar function of `TextView`s and see which `TextView` is crashing.

Comment: I've seen this recently... are you interacting with the Clipboard at all?

Comment: @kushpf In xml mostly, but there could be some created on fly. To use a debugger I should be able to reproduce, but I can't. It's a very rare crash.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt yes, I do use a clipboard in some cases. Please let me know what I should check in the clipboard logic

Comment: I think that this was actually an Android 10 issue, not 9, now that i think about it...

Comment: @jesses.co.tt Play Store reports Android9: Samsung Galaxy S10+ (beyond2q), Android 9

Comment: Have you solved it? Please let me know. I am facing the same issue in rear cses. I am using Scannable String to build string.

Comment: No, I didn't ...